# Как показывать метку / балун всегда в центре yandex maps?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Скажите, пожалуйста, как показывать балун всегда в центре yandex maps?
Например как в yandex taxi.
См. вложение.
Чтобы при смене карты балун всегда был в центре карты:
[Пример тут](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0WkT1GdcrIxshsUQE-GGlEVhisSaxfrYHEhS2F86b9XLA1Ze9EzUP16p43R4hsLN7A=w1920-h1014-rw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не балун, это метка. Вы можете добавить любое изображение так:

```
var style = map.panes.get('events').getElement().style;
style.background = 'url("http://t1.rbxcdn.com/03e863d541704e442033d597945ab2e6") no-repeat center'
style.backgroundSize = '100px'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q41ghm6u/

Comment: @seOga а вы не подскажите, как получить координаты данной метки? я так понимаю нужно получать координаты центра карты.

Comment: Да, если вы расположите эту метку в центре карты, то нужно получать координаты центра карты. map.getCenter()